# Can't get NodeList from current node in java xml parser

Tags: java, xml

So, I have this xml file:

```
<Network id="TestSet01" description="Simple test set to begin development">
  <node_list>
    <node id="n0"/>
    <node id="n1"/>
    <node id="n2"/>
  </node_list>
</Network>
```

And i have this code:

```
try {
        File inputFile = new File("TestSet01_Network.xml");
        DocumentBuilderFactory dbFactory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
        DocumentBuilder dBuilder = dbFactory.newDocumentBuilder();
        Document doc = dBuilder.parse(inputFile);
        doc.getDocumentElement().normalize();

        NodeList rList = doc.getElementsByTagName("Network");

        for (int h = 0; h < rList.getLength(); h++) {
            Node rNode = rList.item(h);

            String name = ((Element) rNode).getAttribute("id");

            String description = ((Element) rNode).getAttribute("description");                               

            NodeList nList = ((Element) rNode).getElementsByTagName("node_list"); //Doesn't work properly here
            for (int i = 0; i < nList.getLength(); i++) {
                //code
            }
    } catch (ParserConfigurationException | SAXException | IOException e) {
    }
```

The problem I'm having is that I can't seem to get the NodeList containing the child nodes of the "node_list" node so I can iterate them individually in the "for" loop after. The code seems to be correct but the list isn't right. I marked the line where I'm having this problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
 NodeList rList = doc.getElementsByTagName("Network");
```

will return you the List containing 1 child :  ...

and  nodes are actually it's children
So you just need to go 1 level deeper before starting a loop

```
Element root = doc.getDocumentElement(); //Network
            for (int i = 0; i < root.getChildNodes().getLength(); i++) {
                Node n = root.getChildNodes().item(i);
                if (n instanceof Element) {
                    NodeList nodes = n.getChildNodes();
                    for (int j = 0; j < nodes.getLength(); j++) {
                        Node theNode = nodes.item(j);
                        if (theNode instanceof Element) {
                            System.out.println(((Element) theNode).getAttribute("id"));
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
```

Comment: Yes, I understand that, but how can I go 1 level deeper then? In terms of java code.

Comment: I'm sorry, but how can I change that code in order to iterate another "Network" child besides the "node_list" one? for example: `<Network id="TestSet01" description="Simple test set to begin development">
  <node_list>
    <node id="n0"/>
    <node id="n1"/>
    <node id="n2"/>
  </node_list>
<section_list>...</section_list>
</Network>